# Loop through subclasses or is there a better way?

Tags: php, architecture

I work for an insurance broker and one of the things I have implemented in my time here is a quote service that takes a client's details as input and provides a list of quotes for a number of insurers as a response.

It currently works as follows:

- index page receives quote data in a JSON string
- quote data is sent to each insurer's calculation script in turn - these scripts are listed in an array in the index page

  - each insurer's calculation consults a database table to see which set of rates it should use given the date that the insurance will start
  - the data is sent to the specific script and a rate is generated and returned to the index
- the index the sorts the results in ascending order and returns them as a JSON string to the sender

The problems with this solution are:

- difficult to test - each set of rates is a monolithic block of code so pieces can't be tested individually
- awkward to maintain - adding a new set of rates for an insurer involves copying the current rates to a new script, making the necessary changes, and making a new entry in the database table with the start date of the new rates. This in turn leads to:
- lots of code duplication between rates

My new partially formed solution is to have a main `Quoteservice` class which contains functionality common to all quotes regardless of insurer or product and `Insurer1`, `Insurer2` etc. subclasses which are called from the index page to get the quote rates. These in turn would have subclasses for each set of rates (`Insurer1May2012`, `Insurer1July2012` etc.). My problem comes in trying to get rid of the need for a database table to pick the correct rate for the start date.

I'd like to be able to say

```
$quoteresults=array();
$quoteresults=array_merge(Insurer1->getQuote($quotedata), $quoteresults);
$quoteresults=array_merge(Insurer2->getQuote($quotedata), $quoteresults);
```

and have each `InsurerX` object use the correct subclass (`InsurerXMay2012`, `InsurerXJuly2012` etc.) based on the start date - probably by calling a function `getStartdate()` on each of its subclasses which returns the date (or timestamp) when the subclass's rate comes into force. Unfortunately, it seems after searching for the best way to loop through a class's subclasses, that this might not be the best way to do it.

The ultimate aim is to be able to just add one subclass of the type `Insurer1Sept2012` for a rate change instead of having to change multiple files and/or database tables. (overwriting previous rates is not an option - the adjustment process needs to be able to get rates for up to 12 months after they are superseded)

**Example of how I see the new version working**

```
abstract class Quoteservice
{
    // Various common functionality here...
}

class Insurer1 extends Quoteservice
{
    public function getQuote($quotedata)
    {
        $subclass=null;
        // This is the bit I'm not sure of...
        // Maybe something like:
        foreach($subclasses as $thissubclass)
        {
            $subclassstart=$thissubclass->getStartdate();
            // Ignore all start dates greater than proposed start date
            if($subclassstart < $quotedata['startdate'])
            {
                $subclasses[$subclassstart]=$thissubclass;
            }
        }
        ksort($subclasses);
        $subclass=array_pop($subclasses);
        return $subclass->getQuote()
    }
}

class Insurer1May2012 extends Insurer1
{
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return 1335830400; // unix time stamp for 1st May 2012
    }

    public function getQuote($quotedata)
    {
        // Calculate May's rate here...

        return $quoteinfo;
    }
}

class Insurer1July2012 extends Insurer1
{
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return 1341100800; // unix time stamp for 1st July 2012
    }

    public function getQuote($quotedata)
    {
        // Calculate July's rate here...

        return $quoteinfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems interesting but can you use some more code snippets and example data to ease understanding

Comment: @RupeshPatel I've added some code to give an idea of what I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to implement this as a single PHP page / script is a non-starter. And once you start to seperate out the logic, everything else becomes much simpler.

> quote data is sent to each insurer's calculation script in turn

I bet the performance sucks big time too.

> each set of rates is a monolithic block of code so pieces can't be tested individually

Then as a minimum, it should be one URL per insurer, which may in turn implement routing to other URLs specific to that insurer. And of course you implement your script as a front controller for aggregating the webservices.

> it seems after searching for the best way to loop through a class's subclasses

You seem to be missing a key point of object-oriented programming - encapsulation.

> use the correct subclass (InsurerXMay2012....

OMG, NO!

You are confusing code and data. No wonder `each set of rates is a monolithic block of code`

> probably by calling a function getStartdate() on each of its subclasses

When you check your email, do you think the POP server reads every email it holds just to find the ones which are addressed to you?

While I believe that the optimal solution would split the functionality across multiple aggregated URLs (i.e. HTTP level architecture) and routing should be driven by data constructs (i.e. a database) it is quite possible to achieve the desired results in a sensible system just using object oriented PHP. But until you can seperate the concerns, layer the code architecture, seperate the code and data and workout how to route the thread of execution through the code properly then you're just making a mess of spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks, but mocking me isn't really helping me. I won't bore you with the details of how the requirements have evolved in the time I've been here leading to the current situation suffice it to say it's pretty convoluted. Your recommendation (routing through URLs specific to insurer) sounds much like what I already have (with the exception of the big ugly calc scripts): client gets quote -> quote is sent to `/quotes/motorhome/` -> `index.php` sends it to each `insurerX.php` in turn which select `insurerXMay2012.php` (using DB data) based on date -> sends back quote -> which is added to results.

Comment: The thing which prompted the attempt at a rewrite (other than the hideousness of the calc scripts) is that my boss added a new calc last week and wasn't sure if he'd done it correctly. The process needs to be simple: add script to correct place in file hierarchy and that's it. Everything else should be handled by the service.

Answer (score 0):

Storing variable data in the classes name, although possible, is not a method I would recommend. There are already built-in constructs for this kind of data storage in the PHP language.

Rather than having a sub-sub-class for each date of each type of quotation, I would use the class's **constructor** to take a date variable, with which it can calculate the required quotes.

For example:

```
class Insurer1 extends Quoteservice {
    public function __construct(DateTime $date) {
        // Do something with the data.
    }
}

// ... would be initialised like this:

$quoteResults = array();
$quoteResults[] = new Insurer1("2012-07-30");
$quoteResults[] = new Insurer2("2012-07-21");
```

The `Quoteservice` class can implement methods such as `getStartDate()`, which will be available to all instances of `Quoteservice`.

You could even go as far to remove the need for `Insurer1`, `Insurer2` ... classes completely, and pass in the name of the insurer into the constructor as another argument.

```
$someQuote = new Quoteservice("2012-07-30", "Insurer1");
```

Comment: Sorry, I've not explained myself well enough I think. The name of the class `Insurer1Jun2012` is just a convenience for me. I was proposing that there be a function `getStartdate()` within the class that returns a date or unix timestamp stating when the rates come into force.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Insurer` should extend `QuoteService`.  They have different (if occasionally overlapping) functions. `QuoteService` is an aggregator of `InsuranceQuotes`. `Insurer` is a provider of an `InsuranceQuote`.  An `InsuranceQuote` depends on who the `Insurer` is and who the `Insuree` might be. So it might go something like this:

```
$client= new Insuree;
$quoter= new QuoteService;
$quoter->calculate($client);
$quoter->show_quotes();
```

with classes like this:

```
class Insuree {

  protected $age;
  protected $gender;
  protected $marital_status;
  protected $drivers_license;
  protected $address;
  //etc. with constructor and getters/setters
}

class Insurer {

  function get_quote(Insuree $client, $args=null) {
    //do stuff
   return $quote; //InsuranceQuote obj.
  }
}

class InsuranceQuote {
  protected $period;
  protected $total;
  //etc. with constructor, getters, setters

  function out(){
    //echo something
  }
}

class QuoteService {

  protected $insurers; //SplObjectStorage containing Insurer objects
  protected $quotes; //SplObjectStorage containing InsuranceQuote objects

  function __construct($args=null){
     $this->get_insurers($args);  //limit the list with $args if you like
     $this->quotes=new SPLObjectStorage;
  }

  protected function get_insurers($args){
    $this->insurers=new SPLObjectStorage;
    //access list of insurers from db(?)
    while($row = $list->fetch_assoc()){
       $i=new Insurer($list);
       $this->insurers->attach($i);
    }
  }

  function calculate(Insuree $client, $args=null) {
    foreach($this->insurers as $quoter){
      $this->quotes->attach($quoter->get_quote($client, $args));
    }
  }

  function show quotes(){
    foreach($this->quotes as $quote) $quote->out();
  }

}
```

Regarding how to subclass `Insurer`: the data specific to each `Insurer` has to be stored somewhere.  If it can be stored in a standard format then you'll only need one `Insurer` class. Designing the tables to hold this data will be the most difficult part of the design process. And without knowing more about the shape of your data, I don't want to suggest a structure.